# How to check status completed/Pending in paypal IOS?

Tags: ios, paypal

i want to check status completed or pending of paypal in IOS:

```
PayPal Payment Success! : {
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.14.3";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2016-06-27T03:27:56Z";
        id = "PAY-78792669RK5256516K5YJZTY";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
```

When I check status: state is approved for both of (completed and pending). Please help me check when status complete or pending? Thanks you so much!

Comment: To check paypal payment you have to verify payment.To verify payment follow this link : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/